# merge sort static method

Tags: java, methods, static

How do I call a normal method into a static method? The assignment says to do a static method for mergeSort and a separate method to do the merging. This sounds like a silly question but would like some help so I can know for the future.

Comment: Who said separate means non-static? Anyway, if want to call it from a static method, you'll need an instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can make both the methods static.

```
public static void mergeSort(){     
    merge();            
}
public static void merge(){
    /* some code */
}
```

If that is not allowed, i.e. you have to keep the separate merge method non-static, then the only way way to call a non-static method from a static method is to have an instance of the class containing the non-static method.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void mergeSort(){     
        MainClass m= new MainClass();
        m.merge();      
    }   
    public void merge(){
        /* some code */
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `static` modifier in the merging method.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this was what was intended, even though it wasn’t explained in the assignment.